# Problems hiding all children elements

Tags: php, jquery, html

I'm having some issues creating a list of collapsible elements.

My code looks like this:

```
<div class="projectscontainer">
    <span class="item destproject" title="ID: 384">Kaoweuzax-Xrjamjhxteaq</span><br>
    <div class="srcprojects">
        <div class="arrow-right"></div>
            <span class="item srcproject" title="ID: 1991">Eovwurxmpgmz 6.b</span><br>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="projectscontainer">
    <span class="item destproject" title="ID: 383">Uxiuhbgbt0.5-Rdsopvxc Fucxbhivs</span><br>
    <div class="srcprojects">
        <div class="arrow-right"></div>
        <span class="item srcproject" title="ID: 1990">Zekgyfrmc-Tpuduwzr Idkudowbi</span><br>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="projectscontainer">
    <span class="item destproject" title="ID: 394">Lyxiyp</span><br>
    <div class="srcprojects">
        <div class="arrow-right"></div>
        <span class="item srcproject" title="ID: 2108">Kdvdz</span><br>
    </div>
</div>
    <div class="srcprojects">
        <div class="arrow-right"></div>
        <span class="item srcproject" title="ID: 2109">Derqi-AA_Boejbvr</span><br>
    </div>
    <div class="srcprojects">
        <div class="arrow-right"></div>
        <span class="item srcproject" title="ID: 2110">Yhdju-SkneLxiyuz</span><br>
    </div>
```

jQuery here:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".projectscontainer").click(function(){
      $(this).children('.srcprojects').toggle();
    });
});
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$result_rules = $db->query("SELECT rules.source_id, rules.destination_id, dest.project AS dest_project, src.project AS src_project, src.    pk_id as src_id
        FROM dbo.FFC_Rules rules
        INNER JOIN dbo.FFC_Destination dest
            ON dest.pk_id=rules.destination_id
        LEFT JOIN dbo.FFC_Source src
            ON src.pk_id=rules.source_id
        ORDER BY dest.project ASC");

$last_dest = false;
$last_src = false;
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result_rules)){  
    if ($row['destination_id'] !== $last_dest) {
        $last_dest=$row['destination_id'];
        echo "<div class='projectscontainer'>";
        echo    "-<span class='item destproject' title='ID: ".$row['destination_id']."'>".$row['dest_project']."</span>";
        echo    "<br>";
    }
        echo    "<div class='srcprojects'>";
        echo        "<div class='arrow-right'></div>";
    if ($row['src_id'] === null) {
        echo        " Source ID for Destination ID ".$row['destination_id']." is NULL ";
    } else {
        echo        "<span class='item srcproject' title='ID: ".$row['src_id']."'>".$row['src_project']."</span>";
    }
    echo            "<br>";
    echo        "</div>";
    echo    "</div>";
}
?>
```

Right now it works if there's only 1 srcproject under the destproject, but I want all children (srcproject) of the destproject to be hidden when the destproject is clicked.

I understand that as only the first srcproject in each destproject is a child in my markup, it is not working. What I don't know, is how can I either fix the markup in my PHP code, or change the jQuery so that it will work.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/for3v3rforgott3n/Q63Dx/2/)

Comment: If you use anyway jquery then why wont you use http://jqueryui.com/accordion/ with custom css or assign at least dynamic id's ($i, $++) to your markup which enables to work with them more efficiently later phases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `find()`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".projectscontainer").click(function(){
      $(this).find('.srcprojects').toggle();
    });
});
```

Looks like there are some extra `</div>` tags causing issues. I've removed them and updated the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q63Dx/3/).

Comment: Same behavior, it only ends up toggling the first srcprojects...my issue is all of the srcprojects that are supposed to be within the projectscontainer div are not inside it. Currently, only the first srcproject is within that div. I'm not sure how to make my jQuery work...ideally I'll need to fix the PHP loop that's generating them but I can't figure out how.

Comment: Does that extra `</div>` in your 3rd project container block really need to be there? i think thats killing it.

Comment: It still needs to be there to close the projectscontainer div, but it has to close it AFTER all the srcprojects for the destproject are printed out, not after each one. I just can't figure out how to make it do that.

Comment: Yep, 1 destination project can have 0 to many source projects

Answer (score 2):

Resolved. I changed my loop to look like this:

```
$last_dest = false;
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result_rules)){  
    if ($row['destination_id'] !== $last_dest) {
        if ($last_dest !== false)
            echo "</div>";
        $last_dest = $row['destination_id'];
        echo "<div class='projectscontainer'>";
        echo    "<span class='item destproject' title='ID: ".$row['destination_id']."'>".$row['dest_project']."</span>";
        echo    "<br>";
    }
        echo    "<div class='srcprojects'>";
        echo        "<div class='arrow-right'></div>";
    if ($row['src_id'] === null) {
        echo        " Source ID for Destination ID ".$row['destination_id']." is NULL ";
    } else {
        echo        "<span class='item srcproject' title='ID: ".$row['src_id']."'>".$row['src_project']."</span>";
    }
    echo            "<br>";
    echo        "</div>";
}
echo        "</div>";
```